# Google API runs into exception 'Over your Quota'

Tags: python, pandas, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using pandas and trying to create a column in a dataframe with the geocodes of some addresses.

Even though I have an active Google Maps API Key, I can't use it to look up addresses in the code below. Anyone has ideas why that might be? I have a premium account and billing activated.

```
from geolocation.main import GoogleMaps
def geocodes(entry):
    address = entry['col_name']
    google_maps = GoogleMaps(api_key='thisisafullypaidandunrestrictedapikey')
    location = google_maps.search(location=address)
    my_location = location.first()

    print(my_location.country_shortcut)
    print(my_location.formatted_address)
    print(my_location.lat)
    print(my_location.lng)

    return ((my_location.lat).astype(str), "," (my_location.lng).astype(str))
```

This is the problem I run into:

**ApiClientException: ('Over your quota.', 'occurred at index 0')**

Comment: Do you have this error when execute only 1 request or bunch or requests?

Comment: When I execute two or more requests.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the region I'm at was not specified.

It worked with the code below for Brazil:

```
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='
region_key = '&region=br&key=apikey'
```